# how would is change background image using UIsegmented control

Tags: ios, iphone

how would is change background image using UIsegmented control ?

i want to change the background image using segment control and after select that image for above process.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more details you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: I guess your question is not clear, Welcome to community but read the FAQ for asking the question.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add Target to segmented controller like
Then, when you click on any segment your "action" method will get called , change background image or do anything in "action" method

```
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(action:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Method implementation should like

```
-(void)action:(id)sender
{
   //code for setting background image.
}
```

Comment: i'm not getting the solution if u can mail me an example so tht it will help me.
mail id - sankalp.kanungo@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link to the documentation for [UISegmentedControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html).

**Edit**

Maybe I had misunderstood your question. If you want to change the background image of a view, you can add your controller as a target for the segmented control.

```
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(updateBackgroundImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

When the `UIControlEventValueChanged` gets triggered for your control you can use any of this methods to change the background image you want.

```
- (void)updateBackgroundImage:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
    self.imageView = [UIImage imageNamed:(sender.selectedSegmentIndex ? @"foo": @"bar")];
}
```

**Original Answer**

As you'll find it that document you can change the appearance of the control in different ways. A few examples.

```
-[UISegmentedControl setBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:]
-[UISegmentedControl dividerImageForLeftSegmentState:rightSegmentState:barMetrics:]
-[UISegmentedControl setImage:forSegmentAtIndex:]
```

When the `UIControlEventValueChanged` gets triggered for your control you can use any of this methods to change the sender's appearance.

Comment: i'm not getting the solution if u can mail me an example so tht it will help me.
mail id - sankalp.kanungo@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Set the IBAction to your segmentbar with `UIControlEventValueChanged` event type and based on selected index you can change the image of your imageView

```
-(IBAction)segmentedChartButtonChanged:(id)sender
{
    switch (self.segmentedButton.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            self.imageView.image = [UIImage imagenamed:@"imageName"];
            break;
        case 1:
            self.imageView.image = [UIImage imagenamed:@"imageName"];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm not getting the solution if u can mail me an example so tht it will help me.
mail id - sankalp.kanungo@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.. May be it will help you..

First take UIImageView and set IBOutlet of that and give name like Backgroundimg And also add Segment value change method And also set outlet to Imageview in xib and outlet of method to UISegmentControl.

```
//.h file

IBOutlet UIImageView *Backgroundimg;

-(IBAction)SegmentChanged:(id)sender;
```

And just add below code in .m file

```
//.m file

-(IBAction)SegmentChanged:(id)sender
{
    UISegmentedControl *seg=(UISegmentedControl *)sender;
    if(seg.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
    {
        [Backgroundimg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"intro1.png"]];
    }
    else if(seg.selectedSegmentIndex==1)
    {
        [Backgroundimg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"intro2.png"]];
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm not getting the solution if u can mail me an example so tht it will help me.
mail id - sankalp.kanungo@gmail.com

Comment: @user3231449 you want to change UISegment background image or UIView's background image

Comment: i want to change background image using UISegmentControl

Comment: i try this code but is doesn't change the image, so plz mail me

Comment: @user3231449 what is your mail id?

Comment: sankalponiphone@rediffmail.com, sankalp.kanungo@gmail.com

Comment: hey bro i need ur help can we chat in gtalk ?

Comment: @user3231449 what is ur issue?

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException'
thts the issue, n i don't understand whts the problm